# Pandas versions compatible with specific python and numpy configurations?

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, conda

Is there a programmatic way to find out which pandas versions are compatible with specific python and numpy configurations?

My interest is to get pandas going within ESRI ArcMAP 10.1, which runs on 32-bit Windows and is built on python 2.7, numpy 1.6.

I tried creating a conda environment for Python compatible with ESRI ArcMap 10.1 by opening a 32-bit Anaconda command prompt and typing

```
conda create -n arcmap101 python=2.7 numpy=1.6 pandas
```

and I get back a Python environment that contains `pandas=0.10.1`

It seems however that it should be possible to build higher versions with `python=2.7`, `numpy=1.6`, but I'm just not sure how much higher.

I tried looking at the [history of the pandas setup.py on github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/commits/master/setup.py) and there is a `min_numpy_ver=1.6` right up through `pandas=0.14` although recently the requirement was changed to `min_numpy_ver=1.7`, so I don't know if that was a new requirement or a bug fix that should have been added at an earlier release level.

And I see that on PyPI, `pandas=0.11` on Windows was built against `numpy=1.6`, while for `pandas=0.12`, it was built against `numpy=1.7`.

But I don't know if the PyPI build was a requirement or a choice.

Is there any good way to find these things out without just asking the pandas developers?

Comment: this has to do with how anaconda creates the distribution. They compile under a certain version of numpy, which then becomes the requirement. You *can* install 0.14.1 with 1.6.1, but you will have to do so w/o anaconda (just use pip). However, IMHO no reason to do so. Later versions have more features and bug fixes. Since you are installing directly, you are not tied to anything.

Comment: FWIW, arcpy works fine with modern numpy, IME

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every package that is built against numpy with conda has that numpy major version hard-coded as a dependency. This version is also reflected in the build string (like `np18py27`). This is perhaps overcautious, as many packages do not use backwards incompatible parts of the numpy API  (and in particular, not all packages actually compile C extensions against numpy), but one way or another, it's how it's done.

Continuum stopped building against older versions of numpy when 1.8 was released, which is why conda gives you an older version of pandas when you tell it to install alongside numpy 1.6.  To see what is there, run `conda search pandas`, and make note of the build strings.

If you need a numpy/pandas combination that is not available, you have two options:

1. Manually install the "wrong" pandas and hope that it works. The numpy API is theoretically backwards compatible, so there is hope here. It might be worth running the pandas tests after doing this to see if it really does work, though. Something like

   `conda create -n arcmap101 python=2.7 numpy=1.6 pandas`

   `conda install -n arcmap101 --no-deps pandas=0.13 # Or whatever version`

   This will put your environment in a state that conda will view as inconsistent, but the packages will be installed there. You can specify the exact version of pandas, down to the build string like `pandas=0.13.0=np17py27_0`
2. Build your own pandas package with the combinations you want. `conda skeleton pypi pandas` will give you a recipe that is a good start (nothing special is needed in the build.sh, or patches required, at least according the the recipe we are using here at Continuum). Then build it with

   `conda build --npy 1.6 --py 2.7 pandas`

Answer (score 0):

We encountered this error message when trying to change the numpy version to 1.22.3 in requirements.txt file:

**ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy==1.22.3**

But when just changing it back to just numpy, pipeline succeeded.

Sample code in **requirements.txt**:

```
    azure-functions-durable
    azure-storage==0.30.0
    pandas
    numpy
    requests
    azure-identity
    azure-keyvault-secrets
```

I have checked some projects and found out that when **numpy==1.22.3**, then pandas version should also be changed to either **pandas==1.4.1** or **pandas==1.4.2**

Sample code in **requirements.txt**:

```
    azure-functions-durable
    azure-storage==0.30.0
    pandas==1.4.1
    numpy==1.22.3
    requests
    azure-identity
    azure-keyvault-secrets
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).